# Are the maps in the The Slaying Stone created using an existing tileset?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures, battle-map

In the published adventure *HS1 - The Slaying Stone*, there are a number of encounter maps containing corridors, furniture, rubble and the like. Were these maps constructed with the expectation that the group would be using an existing set of dungeon tiles, and if so, which one(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Partly

Both *The Slaying Stone* and *Dungeon Tiles Master Set*s were published in 2010 under 4E branding. Therefore, if TSS were expected to use tiles, DTMS would be the obvious choice. But [a complete list of tile sets](http://dmdavid.com/tag/a-complete-list-and-gallery-of-dungeon-tiles-sets/) exists, so we may as well look at all of them.

Encounter 1's map has features (tower, bridge, river, hills) that do not match the ones in [DTMS Wilderness](http://dmdavid.com/master-set-the-wilderness/), or any other wilderness tile set.

However, Encounter 5's map (halls, rubble, sarcophagi, statue, table & chairs) can be built entirely from [DTMS Dungeon](http://dmdavid.com/master-set-the-dungeon/).